# Unable to execute Isdisplayed() method in Android appium environment

Tags: android, eclipse, xpath, appium

I am stuck at a very important part of my automation which i am unable to resolve.

I wanted to execute below code which indicates that:

```
//if modal is displayed
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]")).isDisplayed()) {

//click yes
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]")).click();
}

else {

//else click back
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.ImageButton[1]")).click();

}
```

The problem is that, Appium is not identifying/considering isDisplayed() method, stucks on "if" clause and starts searching for the modal and the time out occurs and it doesn't go to next step at all.

I have also tried to use below "size" method instead of "isDisplayed", but eclipse not accepting "size" method.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]")).size()>0)
```

**Environment:**

Appium version: 1.4.16

Eclipse version: eclipse_Kelper64

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error shown?

Comment: I have found the below solution with the help of my senior developer and now my whole scenario is working perfect. I thought i must have to share this here, so that anyone can take benefit from the following solution of above mentioned problem.
-----------------
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
try {            
     if(driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btnOk"))) != null){
              driver.findElement(By.id("btnOk")).click();
     }
} 
catch(Exception e) {         
     driver.findElement(By.id("btnCancel")).click();
} 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless your xPath exists on the screen the flow shall go inside the `if-statement`, otherwise `else` should be processed.
2. If you are using a Back button press on android, you can use this :

   ```
   else {
        driver.navigate().back(); //else clicking back
   }
   ```
3. `driver.findElement(<locate element>).size()` 
   is not a valid method. You can instead try 
   `driver.findElements(<locate element>).size();`

***s*** being the difference there, return type of both these methods differ. One returns a `Element` while other returns the `List <Elements>` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do same by this way:

```
public boolean isElementPresent() {
        try {
            driver.findElementByXPath("");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //if modal is displayed
    if(isElementPresent()) {

    //click yes
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]")).click();
}

     else {

    //else click back
    driver.navigate.back();

}
```

Comment: Thank you @gaurav for your reply.